# how to make Arabic/Persian characters valid for number input in angular?

Tags: angularjs, validation, arabic, persian

Assume that i have this below `input` in my application:

```
<input ng-model="vm.nationalCode" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]{10}$/" required />
```

and i use `/^[0-9]{10}$/` to force user to enter 10 digit. everything is OK but when user trys to enter Arabic/Persian numbers something like `۰۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹`, the validation is set to false.
i know that `۰۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹` is not a number, but how can i change `۰۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹` to `0123456789` when user is typing and set validation to true?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add the persian numbers to your ng-pattern, like this `/^[۰۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹0-9]{10}$/` (not sure if the persian numbers are consecative; if they are, then you should also be able to do `۰-۹` in the pattern instead of listing all the digits). Then you can convert Persian numbers to Arabic numbers in any string using the following code:

```
const input = 'abc۵۶۷';
const persianNums = '۰۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹';
const arabicNums = '0123456789';

const convertedInput = input.split('').map(c => {
  const i = persianNums.indexOf(c);
  if (i >= 0) return arabicNums.charAt(i);
  else return c;
}).join('');
// convertedInput will now be 'abc567'
```

To exaplain what the code does. It converts the input string to an array of chars, then map each of these chars using the given function, then convert the resulted array back to a string. The conversion function simply finds the index of the char within the persianNums string, then returns the char from arabicNums with the same index.